# R - visreg not using glm correctly

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

For my data.frame df:

```
dichotomous_dependent       Oil_Average_pct_change
               0                     2.26
               1                    -1.13
               0                     4.71
               1                     0.98
               1                     3.59
```

I have a regression:

```
reg <- glm(formula = dichotomous_dependent ~ Oil_Average_pct_change, data = 
            df, family = binomial)
```

However, when I run `visreg(reg, xvar ~ Oil_Average_pct_change)`

I get a graph that looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s05In.png)

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I suspect I may not be using `glm()` correctly but I am not sure

I want a graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUqYB.png) with an S-curve fitted to the data

Comment: What looks wrong / what were you expecting

Comment: was expecting a graph with an s-curve, with all Y-axis values either 0 or 1

Comment: It's plotting the log-odds.  Try `scale="response"`

Comment: http://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/publications/visreg.pdf.  See page 11.

Comment: david your answer is perfect, thank you (`scale = response` as `glm()` argument